# How to properly quit Qt application with worker thread?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the best practice to quit Qt app? I do something like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyApplication app(argc, argv);
    return myApp.exec();
}

MyApplication::MyApplication( int& argc, char** argv ) : 
    QApplication( argc, argv )
{
    m_window= new MyWidget();
    m_worker= new MyWorker();
    m_threadWorker = new QThread;
    m_worker->moveToThread(m_threadWorker);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),m_worker,SLOT(quit()));

    connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), m_threadWorker, SLOT(quit()));
    connect(m_threadWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), m_threadWorker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    m_threadWorker->start();
    m_window->show();
}

MyApplication::~MyApplication()
{
    m_window->deleteLater();
    qDebug()<<"MyApplication::~MyApplication()";
}

MyWorker::quit()
{
    //longer ending operations freeing resources
    emit finished();
    qDebug() << "MyWorker::quit() emit finished()";
}

MyWorker::~MyWorker()
{
    qDebug() << "MyWorker::~MyWorker()";
}
```

the problem is that often the Worker destructor does not run. I am worried that not properly ending the worker can cause an application crash from time to time. I use a camera in that thread so if the camera loop is active freeing takes more time and usually the finished is never emitted and therefore the destructor is never called.

Comment: You should wait for your thread to quit. See [`QThread::wait`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#wait). It's also in the [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details) in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for comments, this solution works

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyApplication app(argc, argv);
    return myApp.exec();
}

MyApplication::MyApplication( int& argc, char** argv ) : 
QApplication( argc, argv )
{
    m_window= new MyWidget();
    m_worker= new MyWorker();
    m_threadWorker = new QThread;
    m_worker->moveToThread(m_threadWorker);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()),m_worker,SLOT(quit()),Qt::QueuedConnection);

    connect(m_worker, SIGNAL(finished()), m_threadWorker, SLOT(quit()),Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(m_threadWorker, SIGNAL(finished()), m_worker, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    m_threadWorker->start();
    m_window->show();
}

MyApplication::~MyApplication()
{
    m_threadWorker->wait();
    m_threadWorker->deleteLater();
    m_window->deleteLater();
    qDebug()<<"MyApplication::~MyApplication()";
}

MyWorker::quit()
{
    //longer ending operations freeing resources
    emit finished();
    qDebug() << "MyWorker::quit() emit finished()";
}

MyWorker::~MyWorker()
{
   qDebug() << "MyWorker::~MyWorker()";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `aboutToQuit` does not wait for the worker to finish. You have to explicitly wait for it to do so:

```
connect(this, &MyApplication::aboutToQuit,
        this, &MyApplication::stopWorker);

// also, change up your connects a little to make shure everything gets deleted properly
connect(m_worker, &MyWorker::finished, 
        m_threadWorker, &QThread::quit,
        Qt::DirectConnection); //direct connection is needed, because you are blocking the main thread by waiting
connect(m_threadWorker, &QThread::finished,
        m_worker, &MyWorker::deleteLater);


MyApplication::stopWorker() {
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "quit");
    m_threadWorker->wait();
    m_threadWorker->deleteLater();
}
```

This will however "freeze" your application while waiting for the worker to finish. If you want to stay responsive while waiting, use a local `QEventLoop` inside `MyApplication::stopWorker` instead and use it as:

```
MyApplication::stopWorker() {
    QEventLoop stopLoop;
    connect(m_threadWorker, &QThread::finished,
            &stopLoop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_worker, "quit");
    stopLoop.exec();
    m_threadWorker->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: thanks, in the first option, why there is m_threadWorker->deleteLater() 2x?

Comment: My bad, it was meant to delete `m_worker` in the `connect` - I fixed it by editing the post

Comment: this solution did not work, because the QApplication was quitting anyway and the worker destructor was not called all the time as it should, but you helped me to figure it out.

Comment: That surprises me. Could you post your solution as an answer? I would be *really* interested in how you solved the problem.